# react with typescript children props almost same as parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm trying to implement some sort of autocoplete, and i'm stuck. 
Basically, i had few nested components

```
AutocompleteContainer 
  Autocomplete
    Input
    Dropdown
      OptionList
```

but, i'm realize that props of Autocomplete same and consist of Input props and Dropdown props, meanwhile props of AutocompleteContainer mainly consist of Autocomplete props and few new props helpers, but, i can't extend interfaces because i'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'getTypeAtLocation' of undefined
```

so i need advice, how i can implement this two components interfaces more elegant ( with DRY principle )

```
export interface AutocompleteProps<OptionValueType> {
    options: (Option<OptionValueType> | OptionGroup<OptionValueType>)[];
    value: Option<OptionValueType>;
    autocompleteRef?: (el: HTMLDivElement | null) => void;
    isFocused?: boolean;
    isLoading?: boolean;
    inputValue?: string;
    onFocus?: () => void;
    onBlur?: () => void;
    onInputChange?: (inputValue?: string) => void;
    onChange?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => void;
    valueRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionGroupRenderer?: (optionGroup: OptionGroup<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    inputProps?: {
        placeholder?: string;
        readOnly?: boolean;
    };
}
```

and

```
export interface AutocompleteContainerProps<OptionValueType> {


options: (Option<OptionValueType> | OptionGroup<OptionValueType>)[];
    value: Option<OptionValueType>;
    isFocused?: boolean;
    isLoading?: boolean;
    inputValue?: string;
    onFocus?: () => void;
    onBlur?: () => void;
    onInputChange?: (inputValue?: string) => void;
    onChange?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => void;
    valueRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionGroupRenderer?: (optionGroup: OptionGroup<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    inputProps?: {
        placeholder?: string;
        readOnly?: boolean;
    };
}
```

see? Single difference between Autocomplete and AutocompleteContainer interfaces is

```
autocompleteRef?: (el: HTMLDivElement | null) => void;
```

same store when i'm see at Input & Dropdown props, they looks like AutocompleteProps with small difference

Answer (score 0):

If your interfaces are the same except for a single property you could use the `extends` keyword like this:

```
export interface AutocompleteContainerProps<OptionValueType> {   
    options: (Option<OptionValueType> | OptionGroup<OptionValueType>)[];
    value: Option<OptionValueType>;
    isFocused?: boolean;
    isLoading?: boolean;
    inputValue?: string;
    onFocus?: () => void;
    onBlur?: () => void;
    onInputChange?: (inputValue?: string) => void;
    onChange?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => void;
    valueRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionRenderer?: (option: Option<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    optionGroupRenderer?: (optionGroup: OptionGroup<OptionValueType>) => React.ReactNode;
    inputProps?: {
        placeholder?: string;
        readOnly?: boolean;
    };
}
```

and

```
export interface AutocompleteProps<OptionValueType> extends AutocompleteContainerProps<OptionValueType> {
    autocompleteRef?: (el: HTMLDivElement | null) => void;
}
```